# renaming table and columns and Transfer schema in synapse pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to transfer table from one schema to another and rename objects in synapse pool dw database.

1. ALTER SCHEMA <new_schema> TRANSFER OBJECT::<old_schema>.<table_name>;

   Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
   Cannot find the object '<table_name>', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

   Completion time: 2020-10-13T08:06:00.9254770-04:00

   I get the error above; however I have proper permissions to rename. Is there any suggestion.
2. rename object <schema_name>.<table_name> COLUMN <column_name> to <column1_name>

   I am getting the below error:

   Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
   Parse error at line: 1, column: 66: Incorrect syntax near 'COLUMN'.

   Completion time: 2020-10-13T07:32:10.5444563-04:00

MSDOCS article followed is  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/rename-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7

Answer (score 1):

1. Below command worked fine for me, check it

[image]

2. It applies only to PDW and not Synapse as per "**Applies to**" section in the document

[image]

Comment: hi, Thank you. I am trying to update an existing table.Which is populated with full extract already.

Comment: hi, can you add more details to this, alter schema will work with loaded tables as well, my table also has data

Answer (score 0):

Having proper permission to rename does not guarantee permission to move the table into a different schema.  This requires "alter" permission on schema <new_schema> and control permission on the table being moved (<old_schema>.<table_name>)

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7#permissions